# Determine which of the following sets of vectors span another a specified vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the vector space

$S=\{(a,a+b,a+b,-b)':-\infty < a < \infty, -\infty <b<\infty\}$

determine if the following sets of vectors span $S$:

$\{(1,1,0,0)',(0,0,1,-1)'\}$

$\{(2,1,1,1)',(3,1,1,2)',(3,2,2,1)'\}$

$\{(1,0,0,0)',(0,1,1,0)',(0,0,0,1)'\}$

I am not looking for the answers, rather the procedure to answer these questions. I have seen similar questions on this forum that ask if the above vectors span some generic vector space $(a,b,c,d)$, and they use Gaussian elimination for the most part. However, I do not know how to solve this problem given an altered vector space. Thank you.

Comment: That is the notation for a transposed vector in my notes.

Comment: I assume the typical notation is $(...)^T$

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to note that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ a+b \\ a+b \\ -b \end{bmatrix}=
a\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+
b\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
In particular $S$ has dimension $2$, because the two vectors in the right-hand side are easily seen to be linearly independent.

If the first set of vectors spans $S$, then the two vectors should at least belong to $S$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=
a\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+
b\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
yields an inconsistent linear system. So the first set is ruled out.

If all the vectors in one of the other sets belong to $S$, you should determine the dimension of the space they span. If it is $2$, you're done.

Of course you can first check the dimension of these spaces before solving the systems, because dimension $3$ would rule out the case by itself.

Comment: Can you not have a set of three vectors that span $S$? I thought only the definition of a basis requires a specific amount of vectors.

Comment: How can I check if the set of vectors yield an inconsistent system? Do I use Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @Michael Of course you can have three vectors that span $S$; but in this case they must be linearly dependent, which is why the check on the dimension is useful. Solving a linear system can be done in various ways, GE is usually the most efficient.